# Confirming List item is Saved before refreshing on Postback

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a simple SharePoint page displaying a simple list of items.

I have a light-box that takes the text of an input and saves a new list item.

When I hit the submit button, the item is saved properly, but the new item doesn't show up.

If I immediatly refresh the page, the item is there, meaning we're really close on timing.

Is there a way to tell SharePoint to confirm that the list item has been saved before proceeding with the page refresh?

Code follows:

```
SPList TargetList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Offer Best Practices");
SPListItem item = TargetList.Items.Add();
item["Title"] = TitleBox.Text;
item["Body"] = BodyBox.Text;
item["OfferID"] = OfferID;
item.Update();
```

ADDITIONS:
I have tried using SPListItem.SystemUpdate() to no avail, as well as SPList.Update(), with no effect.

When I check the SPListItemCollection.Count during refresh AFTER the postback, it stays at the lower number. As soon as I reload the page, the number jumps up to the correct amount.

It's not time, either. I tried setting a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000) after the SPListItem.Update(), and the behavior is unchanged.

It's as though SharePoint isn't registering the new item until the Session or ViewState ends or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your display control is binded on load and your item is getting added on an event handler, you will have to rebind the display control to get the new item during post back. otherwise it will appear on next page load.

Comment: That sounds right, but Page_Load IS firing on PostBack, and so are the methods that trigger .DataSource and .DataBind();. Is there a way to tell if this is working improperly?

Comment: Yes Page_Load will fire on postback but what i am saying is that event handler is fired after Page_Load therefore you are adding items after Page_Load when your display control is already bound. Therefore yopu will have to rebind the display control inside the event handler after you have added the item.

Answer (score 1):

We use the [SystemUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461526.aspx) method instead of `Update`, which may be what you need.

Comment: Gave it a shot, same result. Thanks for trying, upvote for you!

Comment: Dang. Have you also tried SPList.Update (i.e. `TargetList.Update()`)? We don't need to use it in our case, but I have seen others that have.

Comment: Gave it a shot, still no go. I can see the items.count during the page refresh and it is accurate. But as soon as I hit enter on the page address it loads fine.